# In powershell, what's the difference between ps processname* | kill and kill -p processname*?

Tags: performance, loops, powershell, kill

In powershell, is there a difference between:

```
ps theProcessName* | kill
```

and

```
kill -processname theProcessName*
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no difference. Stop-Process can get the process list by itself so you can avoid to use ps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you are using the PowerShell pipeline to pipe `System.Diagnostics.Process` objects (from `Get-Process`) into the `Stop-Process` cmdlet.

In the second example, you and directly calling the `Stop-Process` cmdlet, and are using a *named parameter* to pass in the string to match against process names.

Comment: thanks, in the 1st case, does it mean `Stop-Process` is called once per each row returned by `Get-Process`?

Comment: No.  Cmdlets are capable of dealing with the pipeline and will loop internally for each input (unless they are designed to work over the whole collection, like `sort`).